# nginx "server_tokens off" does not remove the server header

Tags: nginx

nginx.conf:

```
server_tokens off;
```

Why could this get ignored, the header is still sent:

```
Server: nginx
```

No, other included config files do not contain `server_tokens` configuration.

Yes, I did restart all services.

Comment: Considering current best practice infrastructure setup, this has gotten practically irrelevant as I'd install another reverse proxy like varnish or a public CDN service in front of nginx anyways, and they'd strip all the headers I don't want to be shown.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

To cite [the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_tokens) on the `server_tokens` directive:

> Enables or disables emitting nginx version in error messages and in the “Server” response header field.

According to the docs, it thus doesn't prevent the generation of the `Server` header but only prevents the addition of the exact version. If you want to completely remove the servers header, you could use [the ngx_headers_more module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule).

Comment: If I have to compile a mod that is not even included in the package, I could also just alter the source of nginx itself. This is not an option. Off means off.. not a little bit. This is a -1 for nginx :-(

Comment: The setting works as documented. If you want to see anything changed in nginx itself, open an issue at the correct channels. I'm not really following your rant here...

Answer (score 6):

"The setting works as documented"

The above is kinda insane... (Sorry Hulgar Just, but if you don't understand the rant you should probably not answer.)

Nginx doesn't need to broadcast out its version and the server OS, basically ever, outside of debug situations, shouldn't actually be a question. nor should people wanting to stop that insane behavior be a problem to anyone who knows anything about infosec.

As it stands site failures even with the "feature' enabled, results in disclosure of information that is unnecessary for visitors. The absolute best you can do is disable it in all your site configs, but when they die you still have a problem. Patching is the only way at the moment sadly...

Comment: "Nginx doesn't need to broadcast out its version and the server OS, basically ever" - You are right, of course. The problem is the reason they leave it there - Free Marketing. The premium version of nginx allows you to alter the value (Ref: Docs in accepted comment), but they intentionally force you to keep it there unless you mod it out, or pay. Lovely open source community right there ;)

Comment: I think it's possible to unmask an nginx server even without the header. I'm pretty sure there are ways to find out, through microfingerprints, specific behaviour under specific circumstances, characteristic responses. The security impact of the header is negligible.